# WithEvents bug in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I probably encountered an issue of Visual Studio 2015. If you define three handlers of the same event using `WithEvents` and `Handles` keywords, one of the handlers will not be called. I traced this behavior in our software and wrote following WinForms sample project.

```
Public Class MainBase1
    Inherits Form

    Protected WithEvents Button1 As Button
    Protected TextBox1 As TextBox

    Public Sub New()
        SuspendLayout()

        Text = "WithEvents Test"
        ClientSize = New Size(300, 300)

        Button1 = New Button()
        Button1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        Button1.Size = New Size(100, 25)
        Button1.Text = "Button1"
        Controls.Add(Button1)

        TextBox1 = New TextBox()
        TextBox1.Location = New Point(10, 50)
        TextBox1.Multiline = True
        TextBox1.Size = New Size(280, 240)
        Controls.Add(TextBox1)

        ResumeLayout(False)
        PerformLayout()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text &= "MainBase1: Button click handled." & vbNewLine
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class MainBase2
    Inherits MainBase1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text &= "MainBase2: Button click handled." & vbNewLine
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Main
    Inherits MainBase2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text &= "Main: Button click handled." & vbNewLine
    End Sub
End Class
```

After clicking `Button1` `Textbox1` contains

```
MainBase1: Button click handled.
Main: Button click handled.
```

If I compile the same sample under Visual Studio 2012, I get

```
MainBase1: Button click handled.
MainBase2: Button click handled.
Main: Button click handled.
```

Has anybody encountered this issue as well? Or have I missed something?

Comment: This is yet another horrible Roslyn bug.   You can only see it by looking at the MSIL.  The compiler auto-generates a property for Button1 in the Main class, the setter for it has a massive bug.  It uses MainBase1.Button1 instead of MainBase2.Button1.  VS2015 Update 1 is coming soon, currently in RC.  It fixes many Roslyn bugs, try that first.  If they didn't fix it then [report the bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/new).

Comment: After Update 1 this issue still remains. I reported it on [GitHub](http://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7659).

Comment: @VV5198722 I've just encountered the same problem. Have you by any chance found a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug still remains. Here is my solution to this.

I made the handler in `MainBase1` `Protected Overridable`. Subclasses don't use `Handles` but override the handler and call `MyBase`.

This approach has the advantage that execution order of handlers is well-defined.

```
Public Class MainBase1
    Inherits Form

    Protected WithEvents Button1 As Button
    Protected TextBox1 As TextBox

    Public Sub New()
        SuspendLayout()

        Text = "WithEvents Test"
        ClientSize = New Size(300, 300)

        Button1 = New Button()
        Button1.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        Button1.Size = New Size(100, 25)
        Button1.Text = "Button1"
        Controls.Add(Button1)

        TextBox1 = New TextBox()
        TextBox1.Location = New Point(10, 50)
        TextBox1.Multiline = True
        TextBox1.Size = New Size(280, 240)
        Controls.Add(TextBox1)

        ResumeLayout(False)
        PerformLayout()
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text &= "MainBase1: Button click handled." & vbNewLine
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class MainBase2
    Inherits MainBase1

    Protected Overrides Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.Button1_Click(sender, e)
        TextBox1.Text &= "MainBase2: Button click handled." & vbNewLine
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Main
    Inherits MainBase2

    Protected Overrides Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.Button1_Click(sender, e)
        TextBox1.Text &= "Main: Button click handled." & vbNewLine
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I've done the same. Hoped maybe you handled it somehow without changing the code ;) Thanks for your answer anyway!