# Visual Studio 2015 - First Event Handler Stops Event?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0

I'm working on a project which has currently migrated to Visual Studio 2015. I've just encountered a problem I so far have no idea what to do with. In a chain of inherited classes, looking like this:

```
Public Class ControlA
    Public Event CustomEvent(sender As Object, e As CustomEventArgs)
End Class

Public Class BaseForm
    Public WithEvents C As ControlA
End Class

Public Class MiddleForm
    Inherits BaseForm

    Private Sub C_CustomEvent(sender As Object, e As CustomEventArgs) Handles C.CustomEvent
        'do something
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FinalForm
    Inherits MiddleForm

    Private Sub C_CustomEvent(sender As Object, e As CustomEventArgs) Handles C.CustomEvent
        'do something elese
    End Sub
End Class
```

the event handler in the most "outer" class (in this case - a form that is shown to a user) do what it's supposed to do and stops the event. Handlers in the base class are not being called.

Everything worked fine in VS2010.

Anyone had similar problem and could give a hint?

**EDIT**

A little update: Everything works fine when I use `AddHandler` in both classes. If subs are defined with `Handles` - it breaks as described above.

Comment: What framework version were you using in VS2010.  You could try and revert back to that in the project - if it did work?

Comment: Framework didn't change yet, it's still 4.0.

Comment: I guess changes in VS 2015 did break the fact that every Handles clause would add a listener. Did you try change the second sub name ? You never know...

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with VS2010.  Nor does it "stop", the problem is that the event handler in Form2 is not subscribed at all.  Understanding why is not that simple, the VB.NET compiler auto-generates a lot of code.   WithEvents is done by rewriting the C field as a property, its setter makes the AddHandler call.  Big problem with that code is that the property is not virtual.  Every inherited class gets its own C property and it shadows the property in the base class.  Very hard to fix in a clean OOPy way.  Overriding OnLoad in Form2 is a fugly workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm aware of what you've just said. I'm also aware it's not a perfectly written code, but it's also quite an old part of company's "framework" and rewriting it now doesn't really come into play. And the reason I'm accusing VS2015 is the fact that the same solution opened, compiled and debugged in VS2010 works fine. Any idea where that difference comes from?

Comment: It is not supposed to work and never did work.  Nothing new in VS2015.  Why you just noticed the behavior today is very hard to guess.

Comment: I just know what I see, and that is in one case only one handler is entered, while in second one - both of them.

Comment: Some things just stopped working after migrating to VS2015. And the program compiled outside of VS, with MSBuild also works fine.

Comment: @HansPassant I got the info from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290043(v=vs.71).aspx) that it would work...

Comment: It specifically tells you to *not* use the Handles keyword.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, it shouldn't work, I've changed the code to make it look and work properly. But one thing still bugs me - how is that possible it works differently in two versions of the same IDE?

Comment: @HansPassant From what I undesrtood, it explicitly says that if you add Handles in the derived class, the event will be called twice. but maybe I got that wrong I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one with that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608936/withevents-bug-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: I flagged your question as a dupe of that one, since it worked for you